# Associate a new file with Android app

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I would like to register a new file extension (.db_backup) so that all files with this extension open with my app.

Basically files of this type are backed up to email as an attachment. While opening the attachment, I want all files of this type to open directly with my app.

I was successful in doing so by mentioning the android:mimeType = application/*

But now all applications (PDF, APK) open with my app also (which is obvious since * is mentioned). Please tell me what android:mimeType shall I mention in the manifest? My AndroidManifest.xml is given:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.RestoreFromMail"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/restore_mail" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.db_backup"
                android:scheme="http" >
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.db_backup"
                android:scheme="file" >
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/*" >
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Did you fix this? Its your last intent-filter without the scheme that associates it with everything. Been trying to get this to work myself. The problem is without this one the association doesn't work from mail and google drive. I tried adding android:pathPattern but it seems to ignore it.

Comment: Yes, removing the last intent-filter doesn't allow any files to be opened from mail. Still trying to fix it. You can try this: Change extension to .db and change the android:mimeType to application/octet-stream in last intent-filter. Hope that will help!!

Comment: I made some progress today. you can narrow down your last filter by adding android:scheme="content". This way at least not all files will be associated from file manager and other applications. For file and http you will need to add more pathPattern in case there is more than one "." in the path

Comment: I think the reason why pathPattern doesn't work with email until the attachement is saved  is because the file name is not passed. I tested with getPath() in my intent.

Comment: please post some code for adding more pathPattern in case android:scheme="file" or "http"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have the intents setup in my app right now. Just substitute .ext for your extension. Also notice that I am using mimeType="*/*". Had to do this to make it work with Astro file manager. Got it to work with email as well now by removing the android:host="*" in the one with the content scheme.

```
<!-- For email -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
 </intent-filter>

  <!-- For http -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>

<!-- For https -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>

<!-- For file browsers and google drive -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ext"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: The solution works perfectly. But there is a new problem now. When I get Gmail alerts on my Samsung Galaxy S III (Android 4.1.2), it asks me if I want to open the mail using Gmail or my app. If I select "just once" to use Gmail,  the mail opens. If I select "Always", the whole phone restarts. What changes need to be made to the intent-filter?

Comment: Don't have that issue on my Nexus 4, I will have to test on a friends S3. Do you have <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" /> in the intent filter for the content scheme?

Please let me know if you still have this issue!

Comment: Did you have to do anything different? Perhaps post your solution if anyone else encounters the same problem. Thanks!